# MySQL is failing to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5.1

I am building two mysql machines in master-slave config. Master has:

```
mysql> create user 'repl'@'%.%.%.abc.mydomain.com' identified by 'mypassword';
mysql> grant replication slave on *.* to 'repl'@'%.%.%.abc.mydomian.com';
```

So basically anything like my.sql.slave.abc.mydomian.com should be able to connect but on slave if I try:

```
shell> mysql -h my.sql.master.abc.mydomain.com -urepl -pmypassword
```

it says:

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '10.10.2.231' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I think this is happening because %.%.%.abc.mydomian.com is allowed to connect and not 10.10.2.231. I do not want to use IP for connection. How do I make sure that I am able to connect from `my.sql.slave.abc.mydomian.com` without putting IPs into picture.

I don't know if this info is required or not but dns lookup and reverse dns lookup is working fine for both master and slave.

Comment: using just %.abc.mydomain.com is not good enough for you?

Comment: look for a typo in your `GRANT` statement

Comment: @Fox nope. I have tried that already. I used three % because of dots I used.

Comment: @yarek syntax is correct. I have double checked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't have skip_name_resolve set in your my.cnf or in your startup options. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve

Comment: that was the culprit!